# How to upgrade subversion(svn) version 1.6.11 to version 1.8.5 on centos?

Tags: svn, upgrade, svnadmin, svnsync, svnserve

Hj, all

- I'm use svn version 1.6.11 and i'm want to planning upgrade to version 1.8.5?
- I'm run svn on centos 6.4, 64bit. Everyone help me planning upgrade svn?

And help will be greate, thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Centos uses the same versions of all of the RPM packages as RHEL which man not always have the latest and greatest packages. You can try fedora packages. However, you may discover that the libraries Fedora uses are newer versions of the libraries on Centos/RHEL.

There s the [EPEL](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/EPEL) project which is part of the Fedora Project that produces RHEL compatible packages that should work with Centos or RHEL.

Or, you can install the [Subversion Edge](http://www.collab.net/products/subversion) from CollabNet. This will not replace your old Subversion, but install a new version of Subversion. It also will install a new version of Apache httpd which is already integrated into Subversion, so you can use the `http://` protocol with your Subversion repository. This way, you know everything works as planned.

The only thing is that you will have to put the new installed binary directory into your path. I always link these optional component binaries to `/usr/local/bin`, and put `/usr/local/bin` in my PATH before `/usr/bin` and `/bin`. This way, I don't have to worry where things are installed, and I always get the version of the package I want.

Comment: Thanks your answer. i'm not use httpd and client use tortoiseSVN to checkout, commit. I don't know happened problem to "FSFS" ? Because i'm read new feature of subversion 1.8.5 and have a feature "FSFS size"?

Comment: New feature [FSFS Size](https://subversion.apache.org/docs/release-notes/1.8.html#fsfs-enhancements)

Comment: Are you talking about upgrading the server or the client? If you are checking out with `svn co http://...` you are using httpd. Subversion Edge is an easy to use upgrade even if you don't use `http://` when checking out files. I would recommend it over trying non-RHEL RPM packages.